# Transfer dependency to --dev in poetry

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

If you accidentally install a dependency in poetry as a main dependency (i.e. `poetry add ...`), is there a way to quickly transfer it to dev dependencies (i.e. `poetry add --dev ...`), or do you have to uninstall it and reinstall with `poetry add --dev`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can move the corresponding line in the `pyproject.toml` from the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section to `[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]` by hand and run `poetry lock --no-update` afterwards.

Comment: does it work the other way round as well? i.e. I need a package to move from being a dev dependency to a main dependency

Comment: It looks like it did work

Comment: @finswimmer shouldn't it be `poetry lock --no-update`? specifying the `--no-update` flag just refreshes the lock file which I believe is OP's intention rather than locking all deps to the [latest available versions](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#lock).

Comment: Yep, you're right @Kevad. I've edit the answer.

Comment: does this work with the new tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies setup from poetry 1.2?

Answer (score 10):

Since poetry 1.2.0 `-D` is deprecated:

```
  -G, --group=GROUP          The group to add the dependency to. [default: "main"]
  -D, --dev                  Add as a development dependency. (Deprecated) Use --group=dev instead.
```

so you'd do `poetry add group=<group>` and `poetry remove group=<old_group>`

---

You can also `poetry add -D <dep>` and `poetry remove <dep>` in either order. Just be sure to use the same version constraint. Poetry stops/warns you if you use different constraints as they'd conflict.

If you add and *then* remove it will just move the dependencies around without having to completely uninstall/reinstall.